# What is standard for OS X filesystem? e.g. /opt/ vs. /usr/

Tags: macos, folders, filesystem, unix

What does and should go into `/opt/` and what should/does go into `/usr/`?  My understanding is that `/usr/` used to be for user home directories, but since they exist in `/Users/` - what is the purpose now?

Is there a manual or guide to what all of the built-in directories should be used for?  Like what is `/home/`, or `/net/`?

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80902/where-should-shell-tools-be-installed answer your query?

Comment: Thanks @bmike, it does answer my immediate issues, but I'd still be curious if anyone has compiled a more complete/exhaustive description.

Comment: Did you follow the link to The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)?

Comment: @zelanix yes, and it still doesn't adequately address OS X

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Is there a manual or guide to what all of the built-in directories should be used for? Like what is /home/, or /net/?**

Take a look at the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW7) for the most up-to-date information and at `man hier` in Terminal, which provides a "historical sketch" of the filesystem hierarchy (it's included at the end of this answer for reference).

A comment to your question mentions the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml). You will probably come to the conclusion, after perusing [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW7) and `man hier`, that macOS doesn't follow the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml), that's more of a Linux thing. Of course, there are similarities between the FHS and the filesystem layout in macOS because of the common UNIX origin, but the differences are striking. macOS doesn't use any of these:

- `/boot` folder -> macOS uses `/System/Library/Kernels` instead (in older versions of macOS, the folder containing the kernel was `/`)
- `/home` folder -> macOS uses `/Users` instead
- `/root` folder -> macOS uses `/var/root` instead

and `/opt` isn't mentioned not one time in any document (more on `/opt` below.)

A further distiction between macOS and a FHS-compliant OS is the use of `/private`, for example `/etc` is a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/private/etc`.

About `/net`: It is an automounter map (listed in `/etc/auto_master`), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter#.2Fnet) for more information.

**What does and should go into /opt/ and what should/does go into /usr/? My understanding is that /usr/ used to be for user home directories, but since that exists in /Users/ - what is the purpose now?**

Although `/usr` [was used in the past to place the home directories of the users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/pronunciation-for-usr-directory), that's no longer the case.

Nowadays, `/usr` contains user commands (in `/usr/bin` for normal users and `/usr/sbin` for administrative users, like `root`), shared libraries (`/usr/lib`), man pages (`/usr/share/man`), executables that shouldn't be run directly by users (`/usr/libexec`) and other stuff.

It also offers a subdirectory, `/usr/local`, to place programs, libraries and other files that don't come with the base OS.

`/opt` has a very similar role to `/usr/local` and they seem interchangeable. However, from my experience working with other Linux/UNIX sysadmins, there seems to be a *preference* for `/usr/local` in BSD-based UNIX OSs.

**So this is my take on it:** macOS is BSD-based and consequently I'd use `/usr/local`. Note that you can create a program directory and then symlink commands to `/usr/local/bin`, etc, for example:

```
/usr/local/mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so
/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin -> ../mysql/bin/mysqladmin
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.so -> ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so
```

This used to be usual practice in Linux and UNIX too, but the FHS [explicitely forbids](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) it: if you wish to install third party packages in their own directory hierarchy you should use`/opt/<package>` instead. Note that FHS-compliance requires to put configuration files in `/etc/opt/<package>` and variable files in `/var/opt/<package>`.

So, in macOS, I'd recommend that you stick to `/usr/local` as described above.

I'm aware of add-on software like Cisco VPN and [XQuartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuartz) that install in `/opt`, so the above distinctions start to blur.

**`man hier`**

As mentioned above this is `man hier`:

```
 A historical sketch of the filesystem hierarchy.  The modern macOS filesystem is documented in the
 ``File System Programming Guide'' available on Apple Developer.

 /             root directory of the filesystem

 /bin/         user utilities fundamental to both single-user and multi-user environments

 /dev/         block and character device files

               fd/  file descriptor files; see fd(4)

 /etc/         system configuration files and scripts

 /mach_kernel  kernel executable (the operating system loaded into memory at boot time).

 /sbin/        system programs and administration utilities fundamental to both single-user and multi-
               user environments

 /tmp/         temporary files

 /usr/         contains the majority of user utilities and applications

               bin/      common utilities, programming tools, and applications
               include/  standard C include files

                         arpa/       C include files for Internet service protocols
                         hfs/        C include files for HFS
                         machine/    machine specific C include files
                         net/        misc network C include files
                         netinet/    C include files for Internet standard protocols; see inet(4)
                         nfs/        C include files for NFS (Network File System)
                         objc/       C include files for Objective-C
                         protocols/  C include files for Berkeley service protocols
                         sys/        system C include files (kernel data structures)
                         ufs/        C include files for UFS

               lib/      archive libraries
               libexec/  system daemons & system utilities (executed by other programs)
               local/    executables, libraries, etc. not included by the basic operating system
               sbin/     system daemons & system utilities (executed by users)
               share/    architecture-independent data files

                         calendar/  a variety of pre-fab calendar files; see calendar(1)
                         dict/      word lists; see look(1)

                                    web2        words from Webster's 2nd International
                                    words       common words

                         man/       manual pages
                         misc/      misc system-wide ascii text files
                         mk/        templates for make; see make(1)
                         skel/      example . (dot) files for new accounts
                         tabset/    tab description files for a variety of terminals; used in the term-
                                    cap file; see termcap(5)
                         zoneinfo/  timezone configuration information; see tzfile(5)

 /var/         multi-purpose log, temporary, transient, and spool files

               at/        timed command scheduling files; see at(1)
               backups/   misc. backup files
               db/        misc. automatically generated system-specific database files
               log/       misc. system log files

               mail/      user mailbox files
               run/       system information files describing various info about system since it was
                          booted

                          utmpx       database of current users; see utmpx(5)

               rwho/      rwho data files; see rwhod(8), rwho(1), and ruptime(1)
               spool/     misc. printer and mail system spooling directories

                          mqueue/     undelivered mail queue; see sendmail(8)

               tmp/       temporary files that are kept between system reboots
               folders/   per-user temporary files and caches
```

Comment: So, for example, `/usr/X11/` is not recommended?

Comment: @zhermes I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, `/usr/X11` has always been the standard location for X11 in many UNIX and Linux distributions, including OS X. It has been used in the past by Apple itself, on 10.5.8 there was a package called `com.apple.pkg.X11User` that provided X11 in exactly that path. My MacBook Pro still has a X11 package named `com.apple.pkg.X11redirect` installed in `/usr/X11`, I guess from "Lion" or "Mountain Lion", since X11 is no longer included with OS X (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293).

Comment: Note that usr has a backcronym of UNIX system resources, and that's a more apt description of the directory than "user." I'd add this as a minor comment but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: @lefenzy There seems to be two different types of answers when it comes to "usr": it's an acronym and stands for "Unix System Resources" or it means "user". According to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html "some people may now refer to this directory as meaning 'User System Resources' and not 'user' as was originally intended." I don't know which one is true, maybe all of them are correct to some extent... I'll just leave it here as a comment.

Comment: For readers who do not have OS X (for `man hier`): Apple's [Mac OS X manual page for hier(7)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/hier.7.html)

Comment: @jaume, So where is X11 folder now located at?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin, What does bracket 7 mean anyway?

Comment: @Pacerier I checked it for you. The latest version (2.7.11, from https://www.xquartz.org/index.html) is installed in `/Applications` and `/opt/X11`. The "7" in parentheses in Graham Perrin's answer is the section in which the man page for hier is located. For more information on man sections, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean#3587.

Comment: `mach_kernel` no longer seems to be in the root directory, at least when I checked on my machine.  Granted, this could have something to do with OS X v10.11.x's introduction of [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), but that's only an unchecked guess on my part.

Comment: [This post on the InsanelyMac forums](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/321237-cant-find-mach_kernel/?do=findComment&comment=2368961) says, "Apple last used **_mach_kernel_** filename for their kernel in Mavericks, so you won't find any such file in Sierra! Since Yosemite, OS X kernel is now placed in **_/System/Library/Kernels_** under the file name **_kernel_**," so [my earlier guess](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119230/what-is-standard-for-os-x-filesystem-e-g-opt-vs-usr/119265#comment425023_119265) was apparently wrong, it appears.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel Thank you, I wasn't aware of that change, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I read of `/opt` (often [associated with `/opt/local` for MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html)) and of 'standard' uses of paths, I think also of [Fink, which has been around since at least 2001](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64695/8546). Fink popularlised use of the following path:

`/sw`

### An example of careless use of a nonstandard part of the file system hierarchy on Mac OS X

#### 2003-02-06

Virex 7.2, free to all .Mac members, infamously [overwrote Fink libraries](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.os.macosx.fink.devel/3168):

> This is very bad. Fink users, don't install this …

```
/Volumes/Virex 7.2.dmg/Virex 7.2.pkg 328 % lsbom Contents/Resources/Virex\ 7.2.bom | grep sw
./sw    40775   0/80
./sw/lib        40775   0/80
./sw/lib/libcrypto.0.9.6.dylib  100644  0/80    945416  3192711062
./sw/lib/libcurl.2.0.2.dylib    100644  0/80    634480  510417796
./sw/lib/libcurl.2.dylib        100644  0/80    634480  510417796
./sw/lib/libdl.0.dylib  100644  0/80    15124   4193639260
./sw/lib/libssl.0.9.6.dylib     100644  0/80    261776  3001832603
```

Other discussions of the incident, including respect for licensing, included:

- http://article.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.fink.devel/3203/
- [virex 7.2 available at .mac - Ars Technica OpenForum](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=724088) (2003-02-06)
- [Warning: Virex 7.2 could break your fink - Ars Technica OpenForum](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=724323) (2003-02-07)
- [McAfeehelp.com :: View topic - Virex 7.2 for OS X (dot Mac) 'sw' folder in wrong place.](http://web.archive.org/web/20060324181740/http://forums.mcafeehelp.com/viewtopic.php?t=6318) (2003-02-07)

#### 2003-04-16

A [Fink news](http://www.finkproject.org/news/) item:

> **Virex problem resolved**
>
> McAfee has released Virex 7.2.1, which no longer overwrites the main Fink directory `/sw`. Fink users should continue to avoid Virex 7.2.
>
> Early reports indicate that upgrading Virex from 7.2 to 7.2.1 still leaves some problems however. If you upgrade Virex with Fink not installed, and subsequently wish to install Fink, you will need to delete the `/sw` directory by hand before installing. And if you upgrade Virex with Fink already installed, you should immediately run **fink reinstall openssl-shlibs dlcompat-shlibs curl-ssl-shlibs** to restore files which the Virex upgrade may have deleted.

#### 2003-05

[Release Notes for McAfee Virex Version 7.2.1](http://web.archive.org/web/20160314112229/http://downloadcenter.mcafee.com/products/japan/virex/english/v7.2.1/readme.txt) made no mention of the problems caused to users of Fink.

As a side note …

#### 2004-08-31

Observations that [Virex 7.5 was no longer available to .Mac members](http://forum.macbidouille.com/index.php?showtopic=87432&st=0&p=828262&#entry828262).

---

### BSD-related

> … [OS X … My understanding is that `/usr/` used to be for user home directories](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/119230/8546) …

That's still true for operating systems such as FreeBSD and PC-BSD.

Whilst `/usr/home/` is not explicit at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE the path is exemplified in documents such as:

- **For People New to Both FreeBSD and UNIX®: [3. Looking Around](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/new-users/looking-around.html)**

Comment: So why's this downvoted?