# OSX Hierarchy questions and organization

Tags: applications, filesystem, folders, data

I've done extensive searching on these questions and have even come across [others](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119230/what-is-standard-for-os-x-filesystem-e-g-opt-vs-usr), however, they do not answer any of my questions.

- What are ~/Library and /Library for respectively? I can see they store certain applications, but why there and not /Applications or ~/Applications? I'm confused between the 4.
- In my personal system, I see go, git, and android-sdk directories in /usr/local for these programs. Why would these not be stored in those application or library directories I mentioned above?
- I know this is all down to choice, but where do I store, or what is a common place to store libraries such as [boost](http://www.boost.org/) that I would use across all of my C++ programs?
- in line with the question above, where should I store the projects/source files for my C++, Java, IOS, Android, etc. projects? I feel like my system right now is very unorganized with some projects on my desktop, home directory, etc. because of my ignorance on these things, I want to find a good, organized system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X spawns from two different cultures: Unix/POSIX and Mac OS.

Folders like `/usr`, `/var`, `/etc`, the command line shell in the Terminal (`bash` by default) all belong to POSIX environment. Portable software targeting Unix-based systems (like `git`) go into `/usr/local` by default, or into package manager's defined location if installed by it (Homebrew uses `/usr/local`, MacPorts use `/opt/local`).

`Library`, `Applications`, `/System` and others belong to Mac OS specifically. Apple's software, services, and GUIs of third-party apps go there.

The `~` symbol in path is a traditional way to denote path to current user's home folder. Things that must not be seen by other user accounts go into `~/...` counterpart. For example, Mail keeps emails in `~/Library`, but standard stationery templates in `/Library`.

`Library` folders are supposed to be accessed by applications programmatically, not browsed by user via Finder. Since 10.9, `~/Library` is hidden so that users won't unknowingly screw anything there.

There are no out-of-the-box recommendations how to store your files. They will be as good organized as you are good in organizing. They only thing to say in context of OS X is that your files must be in the home folder, but not in `~/Library`, and probably not in `~/Public` which exists to share files with others.

Answer (score 1):

This might be good reading material for all your questions.

OS X Mavericks
Core Technologies Overview
October 2013

http://www.apple.com/media/us/osx/2013/docs/OSX_Mavericks_Core_Technology_Overview.pdf